# The "-c" option does not exist in Laravel (artisan)

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-10

I am trying to create model with command

`php artisan make:model -r -c ManagerModel`

Getting message

`PHP Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException:  The "-r" option does not exist.`

But model and controller is created.

---

I am trying to create model with command

`php artisan make:model -c ManagerModel`

Getting message

`PHP Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException:  The "-c" option does not exist.`

But model and controller is still created.

---

I am trying to create model with command

`php artisan make:model ManagerModel`

Getting message

`PHP Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException:  No arguments expected for "make:model" command, got "ManagerModel".`

And model is still created.

---

[Manual](https://artisan.page/#makemodel) says:

> php artisan make:model [-a|--all] [-c|--controller] [-f|--factory] [--force] [-m|--migration] [--morph-pivot] [--policy] [-s|--seed] [-p|--pivot] [-r|--resource] [--api] [-R|--requests] [--test] [--pest] [--] <name>

I am confused. Why such errors are shown and what they mean if model (controller) created anyway?

```
> php -v
PHP 8.1.27 (cli) (built: Dec 21 2023 20:19:54) (NTS)
```

```
> php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 10.42.0
```